# Different behaviors for variable sized array compilation in CMD vs WSL

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I am declaring a variable sized array like such:

```
int size;
double array[size];
```

BUT the initialization of the size variable doesn't come until the next line:

```
foo(&size, array);
//functions prototype is: void foo(int *, double []);
```

The strange behavior that I can't explain is, when I compile and run this with GCC in WSL, it works perfectly. When I compile and run with GCC in CMD, it acts the same as main function is empty (No errors, just runs and then immediately quits). When I set it to a fixed variable size, it will then work. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: In C++, that's not valid. In C, that's undefined behaviour. You shouldn't tag both languages.

Comment: Can you choose `C` or `C++` ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is sometimes strange, and sometimes it appears to work.

Comment: Removed c++ tag

Comment: When control reaches the declaration, `array` will be allocated with whatever garbage value happens to be in `size` at the time.    It could be anything.  If you're "lucky", it will be large enough for what you need.  But even if it's too small, you may not notice the problem right away.  You will be corrupting memory, but the problem may not become visible until later.  There's no way to know.  That's why you don't do it.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is for a school assignment and the professor's instructions made it seem like this is what was required but I was pretty sure it was illegal.